# How to export ORACLE XE database to have JAVA support?

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle11g

Hello I am quite new to oracle and databases in general.

I have been creating database using Oracle 11g Express for some time, I used only Pl/SQL so far, but now I need to work with Java classes and I just found out Express version do not support java, (when using loadjava, I get error ORA-29538: Java not installed )

So is there way to install java to database or is there simple way to export database (tables, relations, types, data, etc) to some other version what does support java ?

p.s I know that some/most of functions can be done with pl/sql, but I need to use Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle XE doesn't support Java in database (and it can't be additionally installed. For java support you need the full version - at least Standard Edition. Note that contrary to XE you will need license to use this version productive.

You may export / import using [data pump](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_overview.htm)